# extra qualification error in C++

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-errors

I have a member function that is defined as follows:

```
Value JSONDeserializer::ParseValue(TDR type, const json_string& valueString);
```

When I compile the source, I get:

> error: extra qualification 'JSONDeserializer::' on member 'ParseValue'

What is this? How do I remove this error?

Answer (score 286, accepted):

This is because you have the following code:

```
class JSONDeserializer
{
    Value JSONDeserializer::ParseValue(TDR type, const json_string& valueString);
};
```

This is not valid C++ but Visual Studio seems to accept it. You need to change it to the following code to be able to compile it with a standard compliant compiler (gcc is more compliant to the standard on this point).

```
class JSONDeserializer
{
    Value ParseValue(TDR type, const json_string& valueString);
};
```

The error come from the fact that `JSONDeserializer::ParseValue` is a qualified name (a name with a namespace qualification), and such a name is forbidden as a method name in a class.

Comment: Is there any way to make Visual Studio warn about this?

Comment: @altumano: No, but *Cppcheck* can do that and also detect non-ASCII characters in identifiers which helps maintain code more portable to gcc.

Comment: @sharptooth: thanks, Cppcheck can indeed detect those errors. There is even a Visual Studio plugin for Cppcheck (but it's buggy and do not detect in all files)

Comment: @altumano: Is it this thing https://github.com/VioletGiraffe/cppcheck-vs-addin ? If so could you please report the bug - that project is quite alive and there's good chance it will be fixed.

Comment: Hello from The Future. You can now force MSVC to warn about this, by enabling warning C4596 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/c4596?view=vs-2019 . I'd go so far as to have it be reported as an error, by adding the compiler switch /we4596

Answer (score 27):

This means a class is redundantly mentioned with a class function. Try removing `JSONDeserializer::`

Answer (score 17):

Are you putting this line **inside** the class declaration? In that case you should remove the `JSONDeserializer::`.

Answer (score 10):

**A worthy note for readability/maintainability:**

You can keep the `JSONDeserializer::` qualifier with the definition in your implementation file (*.cpp).

As long as your in-class **declaration** (as mentioned by others) does not have the qualifier, g++/gcc will play nice.

**For example:**

In myFile.h:

```
class JSONDeserializer
{
    Value ParseValue(TDR type, const json_string& valueString);
};
```

And in myFile.cpp:

```
Value JSONDeserializer::ParseValue(TDR type, const json_string& valueString)
{
    do_something(type, valueString);
}
```

When myFile.cpp implements methods from many classes, it helps to know who belongs to who, just by looking at the definition.

Comment: `JSONDeserializer::` for the cpp file (or the definition in general) is required. Otherwise, you get an undefined reference. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f8a0cd3f9db6c94 https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6cd1efe94c09d521

Comment: Oh, that's what did it for me.  I had the ClazzName:: in my .h file.  oops.

Answer (score 5):

I saw this error when my header file was missing closing brackets.

Causing this error:

```
// Obj.h
class Obj {
public:
    Obj();
```

Fixing this error:

```
// Obj.h
class Obj {
public:
    Obj();
};
```