# C++ destructor deletes shared memory

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, operator-overloading, destructor

I have program in C++ that does the following: get a non-sorted array of integers and devide it into sub-arrays in accending order. for example. my array is 1,2,3,-2,4
So the output will be:
1,2,3  //sub array 1
-2,4   //sub array 2

the way I requiered to do it is to allocate array of pointers and each cell in that array will point to sub array (also dynamic allocated) containing one series. also, I am not allowed to change the "main" function

now, I have "print" method that print the sub-arrays using operator overloading.

I checked and found the print method working fine but in this piece of code:

```
cout << "\ns3: \n";
  print(s3);

  s3 = s1;
  cout << "\ns3 again: \n";
  print(s3);
```

print(s3) prints fine, but after the assignment operator when print(s3) called again I get a junk output. after some dubugging I think it is something releated to the destructor.

I very apperciate it if anyone can point and identify my problem and come with a solution.
of course I will give the source code

**update**

I want to explain myself little better: after each call to "print", when I trace-into, the first thing that being executed before "print" is the copy constructor. when I set breakpoint in the copy constructor I see that the pointer "src" in the function signature (the copy constructor function) is point to the correct location (the first element in the array), but after the assignmet s3=s1 when I print(s3) again the pointer in the copy constructor is junk

**

here the code:

```
   // HW4.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


//global declerations and indexes//
typedef long int * LONG_INT_PTR;        

//class     
class SeriesArray
{
//members declerations
private: 
        LONG_INT_PTR *stable;
        int *count_arr;   //help array that indicate how many serieses made from the array and how many element in each series
        int count_size;   //  help counter
        int size;

public:
        SeriesArray::SeriesArray(LONG_INT_PTR arr, int n );
        SeriesArray::SeriesArray(const SeriesArray& src );
        SeriesArray::~SeriesArray();
        long int SeriesArray::get_entry(int i,int j) const;
        SeriesArray& SeriesArray::operator=(const SeriesArray& src);
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const SeriesArray& src);//global - not member
};


//members implementation
        //default constructor
        SeriesArray::SeriesArray(LONG_INT_PTR arr, int n )
        {
            size=n;
            int j=0;
            int s=0;
            count_size=0;
            count_arr=new int[size];
            for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
            {
                if (arr[i]<arr[i+1])
                    count_size++;
                else
                {
                    count_size++;
                    count_arr[j]=count_size;
                    j++;
                    count_size=0;
                }
            }
            size=j;
            stable=new LONG_INT_PTR[size];
            for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
            {
                stable[i]=new long int[count_arr[i]];
                for (int k=0;k<count_arr[i];k++)
                {
                    stable[i][k]=arr[s];
                    s++;
                }
            }

    }

    //copy constructor
    SeriesArray::SeriesArray(const SeriesArray& src )
    {

            size=src.size;
            count_arr=new int[size];
            stable=new LONG_INT_PTR[size];
            for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
            {
                count_arr[i]=src.count_arr[i];
                stable[i]=new long int[count_arr[i]];
            }
            memcpy(this->stable,src.stable,src.size*sizeof(long int));
    }

    //destructor
    SeriesArray::~SeriesArray()
    {
        for (int i=0;i<size;++i)
                delete[] stable[i];
        delete[] this->count_arr;
        count_size=0;
    }

    //member
    long int SeriesArray::get_entry(int i,int j) const
    {

        if (i<this->count_size&&this->stable[i][j]!=NULL)
            return (this->stable[i][j]);
        else return NULL;
    }


    //overload = operator
    SeriesArray& SeriesArray::operator=(const SeriesArray& src)
    {
        if (this==&src)
          return *this;

        if (stable!=NULL)
            delete[] stable;
        if (count_arr!=NULL)
            delete[] count_arr;
            //for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
            //  delete[] stable[i];
            size=src.size;
            count_arr=new int[src.size];
            memcpy(count_arr,src.count_arr,src.size*sizeof(int));
            stable=new LONG_INT_PTR[size];
            for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
            {
            //  count_arr[i]=rhs.count_arr[i];
                stable[i]=new long int[src.count_arr[i]];
            }
            memcpy(stable,src.stable,src.size*sizeof(long int));

        return *this;
    }


//***************************************************************************************************************************************************//
//global//

    //overload operator <<
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream,const SeriesArray& src)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<src.size;i++)
        {
        for (int j=0;j<src.count_arr[i];j++)
         {
            stream << " " << src.stable[i][j] << " " ; 
         }
        stream << "\n\n\n" ;
     }

        return stream;
    }

    //print
    void print(SeriesArray src)
    {
         cout << src;
        cout << "\n";
    }  // print



//main  
int main()
{
  long int arr1[20] = {23, 91, -71, -63, 22,  55, 51, 73, 17, -19,
                      -65, 44, 95,  66, 82, 85, 97, 30, 54, -34};
  long int arr2[10] = {0, 1, -7, -6, 2,  5, 6, 7, 1, -1};

  int count[20], i, j, n =20, sno;

  long int *parr[20];

  SeriesArray s1(arr1, 20);
  SeriesArray s2(arr2, 10);
  SeriesArray s3(arr2, 10);


  cout << "\narr1:\n";

  for(i=0; i < 20; i++)
    cout <<  "  " << arr1[i] << "  ";
  cout << "\n";

  cout << "\n\ntable:\n";
  print(s1); 

  cout << "\narr2\n";

  for(i=0; i < 10; i++)
    cout <<  "  " << arr2[i] << "  ";
  cout << "\n";

  cout << "\n\ntable:\n";
  print(s2);

  cout << "\ns3: \n";
  print(s3);


  s3 = s1;
  cout << "\ns3 again: \n";
  print(s3);

  cout << "\ns1 again: \n";
  print(s1);

  cin>>i;
 return 0;
} // main
```

Comment: You delete[] your allocated space and then memcpy into it?

Comment: @Leeor The memory gets reallocated again in between. Not exception safe, but not actually wrong.

Comment: First things first ;-) 1) Your code is not compliant to g++. I assume you are using Visual Studio (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642367/extra-qualification-error-in-c)? To compile your code I had to #include <cstring> and remove SeriesArray:: from your function declarations (only there). 2) Check your program output. Your table is always missing the last array entry, and even worse accesing memory which is not belonging to the array anymore (check the first for loop in your constructor).

Comment: the output in the beginning is fine and correct. the output after the assignment operator is junk (after s3=s1) and I coding in C++ not g++

Comment: @user2826463 Actually I was referring to the line arr[i]<arr[i+1]. The preceeding for-loop rises i to (size-1). arr is an array of (size-1). If you access arr[(size-1)+1] you are out of your arrays bounds. Are you sure about the output of the line print(s1);? When I count the elements I get 19 instead of 20. The entry -34 is missing.    BTW: g++ is the c++ front end for GCC (Gnu Compiler Collection), not a programming language ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your assignment operator, this is nearly right but nearly right is not good enough

```
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
        //  count_arr[i]=rhs.count_arr[i];
            stable[i]=new long int[src.count_arr[i]];
        }
        memcpy(stable,src.stable,src.size*sizeof(long int));
```

I think you meant

```
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            stable[i] = new long int[src.count_arr[i]];
            memcpy(stable[i], src.stable[i], src.count_arr[i]*sizeof(long int));
        }
```

You have the same mistake in your copy constructor

```
SeriesArray::SeriesArray(const SeriesArray& src )
{

        size=src.size;
        count_arr=new int[size];
        stable=new LONG_INT_PTR[size];
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            count_arr[i]=src.count_arr[i];
            stable[i]=new long int[count_arr[i]];
        }
        memcpy(this->stable,src.stable,src.size*sizeof(long int));
}
```

should be

```
SeriesArray::SeriesArray(const SeriesArray& src )
{

        size=src.size;
        count_arr=new int[size];
        stable=new LONG_INT_PTR[size];
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            count_arr[i]=src.count_arr[i];
            stable[i]=new long int[count_arr[i]];
            memcpy(stable[i], src.stable[i], src.count_arr[i]*sizeof(long int));
        }
}
```

Not a bad effort for what I take is your first attempt at 2D arrays.

Comment: Already did what you suggest in your solution but after 4-5 allocation inside the loop the program crash with exception

Comment: @user2826463 See my edited answer, the copy constructor is called when you call print, and because it is bugged you get a crash shortly afterwards.

Comment: Thanks john. you solved this !! :)  can you explain me what was the problem? why the program crash, what actually happened before and after the change?

Comment: @user2826463 You simply weren't copying the stable array properly. stable is an array of pointers. You were allocating memory for each pointer correctly. But then after allocating you must copy from what src.stable[i] is pointing at to what stable[i] is pointing at. You have to do this for each stable[i]. Instead your code was copying the src.stable *pointers*, it wasn't copying *what they were pointing to*.

Answer (score 1):

In your assignment operator you need to copy the contents of each of the individual entries in `stable` rather than copying the whole lot in one `memcpy`.

(Even better would be to change your assignment operator to use copy and swap, or better still use `vector` and make the whole thing a tenth the size.)

BTW you might want to make `print` take a const reference rather than copying its parameter.

Comment: trying that, same result :(. I also update a little bit my question

Answer (score 0):

I tried your program and there are some mistakes more causing the program to fail at runtime (using gcc to compile the program).

```
void print(SeriesArray src)
```

This is a call by value. It will cause the function print to invoke the copy constructor (check [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/911-the-copy-constructor-and-overloading-the-assignment-operator/) page out). As soon as you leave print, src will get deleted (the program will call the destructor). This is a problem because you are using dynamically allocated memory. Better call it by reference, this will force print to use the overloaded = assignment operator.

```
void print(SeriesArray & src)
```

Then there is a invalid pointer as you already read in my comment. Additionally you aren't allocating enough space for stable. You should rewrite your constructor like this - or in a more elegant way if you want...

```
SeriesArray::SeriesArray(LONG_INT_PTR arr, int n )
{
    size=n;
    int j=0;
    int s=0;
    count_size=1;
    count_arr=new int[size];
    for (int i=0;i<size-1;i++)
    {
        if (arr[i]<arr[i+1])
            count_size++;
        else
        {
            count_arr[j]=count_size;
            j++;
            count_arr[j]=1;
            count_size=1;
        }
    }
    size=j+1;
    stable=new LONG_INT_PTR[size];
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        stable[i]=new long int[count_arr[i]];
        for (int k=0;k<count_arr[i];k++)
        {
            stable[i][k]=arr[s];
            s++;
        }
    }
}
```