# OpenJDK - undefined symbol _ZN23G1SATBCardTableModRefBS24write_ref_array_pre_work

Tags: runtime-error, java, undefined-symbol

After successfully building OpenJDK on linux, I'm facing a runtime error on executing java
This is the error -

```
rkbalgi@osboxes ~/jvm_work/openjdk8 $ ./build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/jdk/bin/java -version
Error: dl failure on line 864
Error: failed /home/rkbalgi/jvm_work/openjdk8/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/jdk/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so, because /home/rkbalgi/jvm_work/openjdk8/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/jdk/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so: undefined symbol: _ZN23G1SATBCardTableModRefBS24write_ref_array_pre_workIP7oopDescEEvPT_i
```

The bootstrap JDK used during build is -

```
rkbalgi@osboxes ~/jvm_work/openjdk8 $ /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -version
java version "1.7.0_95"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4) (7u95-2.6.4-3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
```

OS Info -

```
rkbalgi@osboxes ~/jvm_work/openjdk8 $ uname -a
Linux osboxes 4.4.0-53-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 15:59:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any pointers to what could be the issue?

Comment: To start with I would use the c++filt (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/c_002b_002bfilt.html) command on the undefined symbol to unmangle the name and find out what is really not defined.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be fixed by moving template method `write_ref_array_pre_work` to header `g1SATBCardTableModRefBS.hpp` as described [here](https://www.cnblogs.com/sunilsun/p/6078171.html) (sorry, link in Chinese, but this is the only solution that I found)

Answer (score 0):

In $hotspot/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/g1 ,there is two files.
g1SATBCardTableModRefBS.cpp
g1SATBCardTableModRefBS.hpp

you should move template method `write_ref_array_pre_work` from `g1SATBCardTableModRefBS.cpp` to `g1SATBCardTableModRefBS.hpp`

I added it to `g1SATBCardTableModRefBS.hpp` just like the blow.
Notice:You should change G1SATBCardTableModRefBS:: (T* dst, int count) to (T* dst, int count),or you will get [extra qualification error in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642367/extra-qualification-error-in-c)

```
template <class T> void write_ref_array_pre_work(T* dst, int count) {
  if (!JavaThread::satb_mark_queue_set().is_active()) return;
  T* elem_ptr = dst;
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++, elem_ptr++) {
    T heap_oop = oopDesc::load_heap_oop(elem_ptr);
    if (!oopDesc::is_null(heap_oop)) {
      enqueue(oopDesc::decode_heap_oop_not_null(heap_oop));
    }
  }
}
```

It worked for me when I'm using [make version 3.8.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860066/is-it-any-way-to-temporarily-install-make-3-81/860076).